# Chi-square testing help

Tags: chi-squared-test

Let's say I have the following groups:

Controls : [239.473, 247.451, 259.486, 254.329, 240.195]

Experiments  : [252.568, 313.24, 292.972, 269.032, 260.48, 246.808]

My goal is to see if there is a meaningful difference between the Control and Experimental groups.

Every sample is a mean from its equivalent population, and said population is normally distributed. What I then do is calculate means and standard deviation of control sample.

Mean_Control = 248.19

Std_Control  = 8.74

I then apply deduct Mean_Control from every sample in Experiments group and divide it by Std_Control to get the following:

Experiments("pseudo-normalized") : [0.5, 7.44, 5.12, 2.38, 1.41, -0.16]

I then square each element and sum them to get the following value:

Q = 89.5

Since I have six samples, my degrees of freedom value is five. I can then plot a ChiSquared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom, and calculate area under curve for values greater than 89.5. I get absurdly low value, eg. 0.00001.

My question is, does my thought process make sense or is something crucial I'm missing and my question is just silly nonsense?

Comment: "Make sense" for what purpose?  You haven't told us what your objective is.

Comment: I want to see if there is a meaningful difference between the Controls and Experiments. Seeing how all values are means of normally distributed population, I thought that I can consider values in Experiments and Controls array normally distributed. Then I can see if it's likely that normal distribution with mean equal to "mean_control" and stdev equal to "std_control" generated values in Experiments array.

Comment: Presumably you are referring to a difference in *means.*  Even so, statistical significance is rarely the same as "meaningful."  Regardless of those issues, the sample size of each of your data is potentially a crucial element of any valid test: if it's large enough you might be able to justify using a chi-squared distribution, but if any one of those sample sizes is small (say, 10 or less) that will raise issues.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're standardizing the experimental group via numbers from the control. Also, would it be possible for you to conduct a matched pairs experiment? That would be more usual if you want to compare control to experimental.

Comment: @AdrianKeister No, I can't do matched pairs experiment.

I guess my goal was to see if there is meaningful difference between control population and experiment population via something other than t-test or its other versions. So for that, I tried to express experiment population via control population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are stripcharts of your control and treatment
observations (Lower plot for control.) Using R:

```
ctrl = c(239.473, 247.451, 259.486, 254.329, 240.195)
trtm = c(252.568, 313.24, 292.972, 269.032, 260.48, 246.808)
 stripchart(list(ctrl, trtm), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch=20)
```

[image]

Although there are few observations and a lot of overlap,  the locations seem to differ and it would be
risky to assume that the dispersions are the same.
Both are consistent with sampling from normal
distributions.

My first move would be to use a Welch two-sample t test, which does not assume equal variances, to
test for a significant difference in means.
There is a significant difference at the 7% level, but not at the 5% level

```
t.test(ctrl, trtm)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  ctrl and trtm
t = -2.1757, df = 6.3361, p-value = 0.07009
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -51.343962   2.684228
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 248.1868  272.5167
```

Other than the fact that it doesn't (quite) show a significant difference in means at the 5% level,
what is your objection to doing the t test?

Comment: I used Python's Pingouin module to do Welch, like you did, and got p-value of 0.07 with some additional stuff - namely power of test, which was in range of ~0.4, which is quite low.  I suspect that this is due to rather low amount of samples. It's not that I object to t-test, but it seems to be rather underpowered to me. 

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Pooled 2-sample t seems inappropriate looking at stripcharts, but it does not reject at 5% level. Nonparametric tests will have poor power with such small samples (unless most all Control values are below any Treatment value). I don't see reasonable alternative to Welch t.

Comment: I did one sided welch t test in pingouin and I got ~ 0.03 (well, obviously) instead of two sided, and the power marginally improved to ~0.5. So I guess I'll report it like this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.